# Node.js + Passport.js can't authenticate different clients unless served from same app

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to build a RESTful API using node as my server technology.

I want to build my API so that any client can use it. In the near future I want to be able to build an iOS app and an Android app. So far for testing, I've been using the views in sails.

I've added Passportjs to help with authenticating users through other providers and everything seems to work great when I'm using it from within my sails app.

I created a different app that uses my API with AngularJS to test it out. I've hit a roadblock though. I'm trying to hit my auth endpoints but I all I keep getting are errors.

whenever I try to hit `/auth/:provider` it tries to do the flow but it gets an error when attempting to go to the provider's page to do the auth:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={TOKENREMOVED}. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And in my angular app I am doing:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:1337/auth/twitter').then(){...})
```

When I try to login flow with the views in my node app it works correctly.

I'm guessing if I can't even do the auth flow in a different angular app, I might not even be able to do it on iOS or Android.

Is there something different I should be doing? I'm really confused as to how to progress passed this point so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the user's browser to Twitter's `/oauth/authenticate` URL, you do this with `$window.location()` in Angular.  The `$http.get()` method makes an XHR request, which is different from a redirect.

Comment: So I would handle the oauth flow on the client instead of simply calling my servers `/auth/twitter`? And I'm assuming that once the auth is complete, I would redirect back to my webapp with some sort of URL param that I could pass back to my server?

Comment: Twitter will redirect the user back to your site with an `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`.  Those are the values that you want to send back to your server, and your server will verify the tokens.